# How can I find replacement extruded aluminum?

Tags: replacement, aluminum

How can I find replacement extruded aluminum? Is there a standard way to describe it for online search or working with a supplier?

This piece was used in one of my windows. I cleaned it in a degreaser which contains lye so the aluminum corroded.

The metal is pitted, not just discolored. I could probably get a wire brush on a Dremel but I figured new extruded aluminum is not expensive.

This part is a track for the casement window operator. I can find operator cranks online that look similar to mine but hard to be certain that the track is the same.

[image: side]

[image: long]

Comment: You might be able to clean it up so it looks like new again. I don't know how to, but I know it has been done.

Comment: Figure out who made the window and contact them for a replacement part? But it seems far easier to clean it. Have you tried some buffing compound and a ScotchBrite type pad?

Comment: I'd be curious to see toothpaste and a brush on a dremel.

Comment: *wall curtain track for RV* https://www.google.com/search?q=wall+curtain+track+for+rv&tbm=isch&ved=2ahUKEwiEjLz1p5n2AhVPUc0KHR4VAAsQ2-cCegQIABAA&oq=wall+curtain+track+for+rv&gs_lcp=CgNpbWcQAzoECAAQQzoFCAAQgAQ6BggAEAUQHjoGCAAQCBAeOgQIABAeUPQGWMEQYNESaABwAHgAgAGHAYgBqQWSAQM3LjGYAQCgAQGqAQtnd3Mtd2l6LWltZ8ABAQ&sclient=img&ei=X_wXYsTgOc-itQaeqoBY&bih=708&biw=874&client=firefox-b-1-d

Comment: What does it do? *It's a curtain track.* - then that's what you search for. - Could be *aluminum track for window sweep* but none of that looks right.

Comment: It's a "track for the casement window operator", so I used a search engine for "casement window track" and found dozens of places to buy them. Maybe [this will help](https://searchengineland.com/guide/how-to-use-google-to-search).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to polish that extrusion and re-use it. I'd try a fine-grit sandpaper or wire brush and then progressively finer grits until it looks clean. I don't think there's any reason to go for a mirror finish as you'll probably end up painting it with the rest of the window.

It looks like there's another part to it--[a rubber, vinyl, felt, or "hairy worm pile seal (pictured below)](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=pile%20window%20seal%20aluminum%20extrusion&atb=v308-1&iax=images&ia=images) --that was originally installed in the channel and is now missing. You should be able to find a replacement seal for the old extrusion.

[image]

Even if you can't find an exact match and replace the aluminum extrusion, something similar with an included seal would likely be an improvement.

Answer (score 1):

You could use gooqle images search for "extrusion profiles window strip or edge." Or you could ask at your local autobody shop. They have all sorts of buffing tools and compounds.